# Windows Phone - Brushes does not exist

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I want to change the foreground of my button, but I got an error saying "The name 'Brushes' does not exist in the current context"

Here is the code :

```
 private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button but = new Button();
        but.Content = "Task";
        but.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];

        but.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;  //error here

        TaskPanel.Children.Add(but);
    }
```

Plus, using System.Drawings doesn't work.
I tried several alternatives, but my application doesn't recognize Windows.UI.Colors neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

```
but.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
```